Disable Angular Animations as a User
We are automating a third party application using RPA. The application is written in Angular 17 and has many default animations enabled (like expanding a collapsed panel) - which lead to delays and possible problems.
The page is unaffected by 'prefers-reduced-animation' or the OS setting to disable animations.
I have also tried to inject a global style via JavaScript * { animations: none!important; transitions: none!important } which had no effect.
It seems Angular is setting the relevant properties directly in the .style attribute of the elements (including !important)
We cannot access/change the source code of the application, but we can execute custom JavaScript on the page. I ideally would like a robust solution which disables all transition/animations.

maybe this JS answer will help you SO Answer
